# Setting up Basic Authentication for Java RESTful web service with IIS7 (front-end)-Tomcat 5.5 (back-end) web servers

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, iis, basic-authentication

I have IIS7 hooked into Tomcat 5.5 via the AJP connector. IIS is the front-end web server. Tomcat is the back-end web server. I also have a RESTful web service compiled with Java 1.6 and employing the the Jersey API, version 1.19.

I wish to setup Basic Authentication for the RESTful web service. However, I am unsure how to proceed, thanks to the inclusion of IIS as the front-end web server. **Is it possible to setup Basic Authentication, given my system setup includes IIS and, if so, how do I proceed?**

Second, the RESTful web service is running inside an existing Tomcat webapp. This part is just as important: The webapp is basically a vendor solution. It's crucial that enabling Basic Authentication *only* affects the RESTful web service and leaves the rest of the webapp intact. **Is it possible to apply Basic Authentication to just the RESTful web service and how would this be done?**

E.g.:

- IIS is at https://myserver.com
- Tomcat webapp (via AJP connector) is at https://myserver.com/vendorapp
- RESTful web service is at https://myserver.com/vendorapp/rest/foobar

Could I use url-pattern with Basic Authentication such that it only affects the RESTful web service and leaves the rest of the webapp unscathed, i.e. `/rest/*`

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Maybe nginx is another choice to do this thing.

Comment: We can define two locations and only one of them is enabled with HTTP Basic Auth. More detail discussion can be found from this link [Secure Existing RESTful Services—No Need to Change Code](https://dzone.com/articles/secure-existing-restful-services-no-need-for-chang)